# PHP how to disable HREF once it is clicked using Jquery or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My problem is how to disable `href` once it is clicked? Please help me I badly need to finish this program in PHP

> Style.css

```
.disabled {
pointer-events: none;
```

}

Comment: href cannot be disabled

Comment: maybe you should hide href

Comment: Yes but how sir?

Comment: Hide will be helpful but how??

Comment: I want to hide it when it was clicked.

Comment: Sounds like you may need to get a javascript tutorial and read it

Comment: Also it is not PHP related

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I assume you want to send the cart to PHP
2. I assume you do NOT want the page to change

```js
$(function() {
  $(".cart").on("click",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // never follow the link
    var $thisLink = $(this);
    if ($(this).not(".added")) {
      $.post(this.href,function(data) { // return { "successfullyAdded":"true" } from PHP
        if (data.successfullyAdded=="true") {
          $thisLink.addClass("added"); 
          $thisLink.text("added"); 
        }
      });
    });
  });
});
```

using

```
<a class="cart" href="?add=<?php echo($i); ?>">Add to cart</a>
```

Comment: Yes sir you are correct but how can I  do that code ? will I create new page and name it cart.js? sorry sir :( Im just new to php sorry Take a look at my full code sir thank you so much

Comment: It is not working though

Comment: You have not given enough information - if you insert my code before load of the page it works. After load: remove the $(function () {})

Answer (score 1):

You Can try this technique

```
$("#add_cart").one('click',function(){
    alert("Item Successfully Added.");
});
```

JsFiddle Link https://jsfiddle.net/b143vsuy/

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#your_link_id").click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<a href="?add=<?php echo($i); ?>" id="your_link_id">Add to cart</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need that 'link' further then You can find your answer below:

```js
$('a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).removeAttr('href');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="?add=<?php echo($i); ?>">Add to cart</a>
```

Comment: That will stop it from working completely. You need to allow the click or process the click and remove the click. Add to cart normally does not leave the page

Comment: @mplungjan  agreed with you

Comment: @mplungjan Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Some way very short:

```html
<a href="?add=<?php echo($i); ?>" onclick="this.href='#';">Add to cart</a>
```